# Combine results in a data set via common values in each column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-structures, key-value

I have a table like this:

```
Group | Item
--------------------
323003  618-2144929
319373  618-2144929
108760  618-2144929
99868   618-2144929
305321  618-2144929
108761  618-2144929
319373  600-2144929
305321  600-2144929
108761  600-2144929
108760  600-2144929
99868   600-2144929
323003  600-2144929
99868   300-PVC01080
305321  300-PVC01080
108761  300-PVC01080
323003  300-PVC01080
319373  300-PVC01080
160646  100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
333757  400-S1-0812
10000   110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
333757  100-S1-0812
20000   400-S1-0812
```

Need to take each and every item and identify the assigned groups.

```
618-2144929 -\> 108760,108761,305321,319373,323003,99868    
600-2144929 -\> 108760,108761,305321,319373,323003,99868    
300-PVC01080 -\> 108761,305321,319373,323003,99868    
100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30 -\> 160646     
400-S1-0812 -\> 333757,20000          
110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30 -\> 10000          
100-S1-0812 -\> 333757
```

For all the identified groups for a particular item, need to get common items together, as follows.

```
108760 - \> 618-2144929,600-2144929
108761 - \> 618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
305321 -\> 618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
319373 -\> 618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
323003 -\> 618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
99868 -\> 618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
333757 -\> 400-S1-0812,100-S1-0812
20000 -\> 400-S1-0812
10000 -\> 110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
160646 -\> 100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
```

Need to combine both sets together and get the final out put.

Final output need to like this:

```
GROUPS| ITEMS
---------------

108760,108761,305321,319373,323003,99868        618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
333757,20000                                    400-S1-0812,100-S1-0812
160646                                          100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
10000                                           110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
```

Need a solution using Python and get the final output mentioned above.

Comment: I think there's an error in your example. 108760 doesn't have, but it does in the desired output 300-PVC01080

Comment: @Mark, 618-2144929,600-2144929 items are in 108760 group. As 300-PVC01080 is already in other groups that 618-2144929,600-2144929 items are assigned (groups are : 108761,305321,319373,323003,99868) we need to get 108760 also into final grouping.

ex: 100 - 201 (group - item),
101 - 201,101 - 700,102  - 700

Final grouping:

(groups - items)
100,101,102 - 200,700

Comment: sorry I don't follow

Comment: 108760 doesn't have the item 300-PVC01080, but it does in the desired output. That makes no sense

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combine results in a data set via common values in each column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76918549/combine-results-in-a-data-set-via-common-values-in-each-column)

Comment: @maciek Above thread is requested for sql

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
dfr = (df.groupby(by=['Item'])
         .agg(list)
         .apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x['Group'])), axis=1)
         .reset_index()
         .groupby(by=[0])
         .agg(list)
         .reset_index()
         .rename(columns={0: 'Group'})
         .applymap(lambda x: ','.join(list(map(str, x)))))
```

Output:

```
                                      Group                     Item
0                                     10000   110-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
1                              20000,333757              400-S1-0812
2  99868,108760,108761,305321,319373,323003  600-2144929,618-2144929
3         99868,108761,305321,319373,323003             300-PVC01080
4                                    160646   100-DGMX2-5-PP-BH-B-30
5                                    333757              100-S1-0812
```

Comment: Thank you, Jeril. However I need to combine 2 and 3 together and 1 and 5 also into another group like this.

108760,108761,305321,319373,323003,99868        618-2144929,600-2144929,300-PVC01080
333757,20000                                    400-S1-0812,100-S1-0812

Because 618-2144929,600-2144929 items are in 108760 group. 
As 300-PVC01080 is already in other groups that 618-2144929,600-2144929 items are assigned (groups are : 108761,305321,319373,323003,99868), we need to get 108760 also into final grouping as it is assigned to 300-PVC01080.

Could you please help on that?

Comment: that can be done using a for loop, i leave that for you